# setAttribute('display','none') not working

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function classInfo(e){
    document.getElementById('classRight').setAttribute('display','none');
    alert(e);   
}
```

I think this code is very straightforward bit it's not working, and is not hiding the  element in question. I am getting my alert, which makes me think there is no issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From w3schools: "The getElementById() method accesses the first element with the specified id."  Check and make sure there's not another element in your doc with that id.

Comment: @MikeMytkowski All `id` s must be unique, or else you have invalid HTML here. And please, there are *much, much* better reference material than W3Schools out there.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: yep, I stand corrected. proper answer is below.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`display` is not an attribute - it's a CSS property. You need to access the style object for this:

```
document.getElementById('classRight').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Additionally you could `document.getElementById("classRight").setAttribute("style","display:none;");`, but I recommend you use the other method.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
setAttribute("hidden", true);
```

Comment: Display:none and hidden: true do very different things

Comment: Both parameters must be a string
SO use setAttribute("hidden", "true") if you want to use this solution

Comment: If it doesn't work, try using `element.removeAttribute` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
```