# How can I make rows show or hide based on a value of a selectBox?

Tags: javascript

The schema is like that, I use *SelectBoxes* and *Text*

```
SelectBox - country
SelectBox - *county1*  Text-*countyText1*
SelectBox - *county2*  Text-*countyText2*
SelectBox - *county3*  Text-*countyText3*
```

Based on the *country's value*, I'll **show** or **hide** *counties* *as a row*. I mean if the value of country is 1, county1 *selectBox* and *countyText1* will be shown, others will be hidden.

If the value of country is 2, the third row will be hide, first two rows will be shown,

How to do that?

I don't want to use if else statement, cause this is just an example. There may be more values than only three value...

I try to do as:

```
var source = document.getElementsByName("country")[0];
var sourceValue = source.options[source.value]; // sourceValue will be 1 or 2 or 3 for this example

var showHideArray = ["county1","county2","county3"];
for (var i = 0; i<showHide.array.length; i++){
    if(source.value>i){
        document.getElementByname[showHideArray[i]].setAttribute("type","display:show")
    } else{
        document.getElementByname[showHideArray[i]].setAttribute("type","display:none")

    }
}
```

I am sure I have mistakes as I write `"display:show"`, but how can I do what I want? Also **I want to hide** *all row, selectBox* and *Text*

Comment: There are many mistakes in your code. It would be easier to advise if we could see more of your code, but right off the bat: `getElementByname` isn't a thing, use `querySelector('[name=' + showHideArray[i] + ']')` . Styles aren't changed through `setAttribute`, rather `element.style.display="none"`

Comment: Cant I do this job without using querySelector, but using document.getElementsByName? And i am just trying to figure out what code to write. I only have selectBoxes and Text Boxes. I want to control them by getting the value of first Select Box which is for country

Comment: on this link, someone said that setAttribute worked, i copied it from there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981454/setattributedisplay-none-not-working

Comment: why don't you want to use querySelector? It's a good tool for the job - superior to getElementsByClassName because it is live, whereas the latter is written at page load and sits unaffected.

Comment: Honestly, if you paste in your HTML and show what we're working with, we can advise you, but be open that the way you're trying to do it probably won't be the way someone shows you how to do it...

Comment: Hello, i added html part of that page, but it seems too complicated for me. In the page, i see header and selectBox and text. I have form pages. Every page shows one html.. i updated the question

Comment: I think this is not corresponding html. where is `country` name in html?

Comment: Yes it doesnt correspond. I mean its so complicated project. I have nothing to do with html. It creates forms based on other things(idk) I am just expected to get rows depending on the value in the country SelectBox, if its 1, only first row will be shown, other two will be hidden.. like that. I hope i am clear

Comment: There are forms, many forms can be added manually, and this is the html as i know. We create forms manually without writing code, this must be the base html it refer to, as i am guessing. But im expected to do this with DOM, ill not use any html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want show and hide some `textbox` based on your selectbox value.

You have to go through all `options` and set `display=none` for all correspond text (based on name) except selected option value. For selected option value you must find correspond `textbox` and set `display=inline or block`

```js
 function change() {
            var source = document.getElementsByName("country")[0];

            for (var i = 0; i < source.options.length; i++) {
                if (source.selectedOptions[0].value == source.options[i].value) {
                    document.getElementsByName(source.options[i].value)[0].style.display = "inline";
                    document.getElementsByName(source.options[i].value)[0].parentElement.style.display = "inline";
                    document.getElementsByName(source.options[i].value)[0].value = source.options[i].value;

                }
                else {
                    document.getElementsByName(source.options[i].value)[0].style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementsByName(source.options[i].value)[0].parentElement.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<div>
        <select name="country" onchange="change();">
            <option value="county1">county1</option>
            <option value="county2">county2</option>
            <option value="county3">county3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        county1: <input type="text" name="county1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        county2: <input type="text" name="county2" />
    </div>

    <div>
        county3: <input type="text" name="county3" />
    </div>
```

Comment: I thought I replied, sorry. Thank you for your help. But would this work for hiding row completely? I mean if the value of SelectBox is 1, only first row will be shown. Other two selectBoxes and Texts will be hidden, not only Text

Comment: Yes you can do it. I edit my answer to hide whole row

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. But I guess you may get me a bit wrong :) I meant, there is a value for first `SelectBox`, it can have values as `1,2 or 3.` And there are `3 rows under of that SelectBox`, each row has one SelectBox and one Text. And I named them in my question. If first SelectBox's value is 1, only first row( so one SelectBox and Text will be shown, others will be hidden)