# How can I make enable other SelectBox values when I change the value of another SelectBox?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 `SelectBoxes`, they can have values as `1,2,3`.

Their names are "a","b","c". I only want to reach them using their names.

When I use this function, on first `SelectBox's onChange` event,

```
var  source = document.getElementsByName("a")[0]; 
document.getElementsByName("b")[0].options[source.value].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
document.getElementsByName("c")[0].options[source.value].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
```

And for second SelectBox's onChange event,

```
var  source = document.getElementsByName("b")[0];
document.getElementsByName("c")[0].options[source.value].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
```

It works. But if i change firstSelectBox's again... then I cant use the first value which was disabled, but should be enabled now.

I hope I am clear about what i want to do.

Here is the pic:

[image]

*it doesnt get into for loop*...

```
var optSecond = document.getElementsByName("nameSelectBox16257264317217")[0].options;

            for (var i = 1; i < optSecond.length; i++) {
                optSecond[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
                console.log(optSecond[i].value);
            }

            var optThird = document.getElementsByName("nameSelectBox162572643286379")[0].options;
            for (var i = 1; i < optThird .length; i++) {
                optThird[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
                console.log(optSecond[i].value);

            }

            var source = document.getElementsByName("nameSelectBox162572640796915")[0];
            document.getElementsByName("nameSelectBox16257264317217")[0].options[source.value].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementsByName("nameSelectBox162572643286379")[0].options[source.value].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: why don't you try to use Jquery instead and use if else condition?

Comment: That's happen because you never enable it. Please make a executable snippet

Comment: This is a project which is full of forms.. All forms have same html but when i open on browser they all have different pages. So i dont know how to do it... Couldnt you help me by the question i tried to tell? thanks.. @AlirezaAhmadi

Comment: someone showed me this way, and i went so... but  i couldnt succeed @AskWarvin

Comment: @helloWorld check this how to use jquery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown

Comment: Thanks, but i am expected to do this using their unique names.. not by id. @AskWarvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove all disable attribute **before** set disable for a specific options.

And note that options is zero based index, so you have to use this `options[source.value - 1]` instead of `options[source.value]`.

```js
      function change() {
            var optB = document.getElementsByName("b")[0].options;
            for (var i = 0; i < optB.length; i++) {
                optB[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
            }

            var optC = document.getElementsByName("c")[0].options;
            for (var i = 0; i < optC.length; i++) {
                optC[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
            }

            var source = document.getElementsByName("a")[0];
            document.getElementsByName("b")[0].options[source.value - 1].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
            document.getElementsByName("c")[0].options[source.value - 1].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        function changeSecond() {
            var optC = document.getElementsByName("c")[0].options;
            for (var i = 0; i < optC.length; i++) {
                optC[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
            }


            var source = document.getElementsByName("b")[0];
            document.getElementsByName("c")[0].options[source.value - 1].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        }
```

```html
    <select name="a" onchange="change()">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="b" onchange="changeSecond()">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="c">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, i will try to do the same by following your code. I appreciate a lot!

Comment: Hello, I did what you showed me. But when i change the firstSelectBox's value, i  cant select the value which was disabled before, it doesnt get enabled

Comment: For example, i choose 1 in first selectBox, and 3 in second selectBox, then if i change 1 to 2 in first SelectBox, i still cant choose  1 in second SelectBox

Comment: in code snippet you made it worked, but idk why it didnt do the same on my local

Comment: As you said my snippet is work correctly and if you apply this code in your local must be Ok

Comment: Thank you, ill inform you once i get same result. But thank you for your solution. It helps me to understand what to do

Comment: Sir, i have a problem, i found the reason.. It doesnt enable(removeAttributes) it just setAttributes, because it doesnt get into for loop... Idk why, but it doesnt go in for loop. How to do it?

Comment: You need to make loop all over the options and remove  `disable` attribute

Comment: Could u please look at my code i am updating in my question, i tried to adjust your code to myself since i didnt want to use options[0]

Comment: It seems to be OK. But note that in `options[source.value]` the `source.value` is index of options like `array[0]`  if you want to find option by value you need to filter the options, However in your sample your value was `1,2,3` and `options[source.value - 1]` is still working

Comment: yeah, there are 4 options, but the value of 1 is in index 1. option. Thats why I wanted to do it as `options[source.value]` but in my code , it doesnt get in `for loop` because i wrote `console.log` and it didnt write the `value` on the `console` and i dont know how i can solve this

Comment: log `optSecond ` and see is there any options?

Comment: no , it doesnt log anything in `for loop`

Comment: Sorry without executable code anyone can't help you

Comment: you are right.. Thank you for your big help though. At least now i understand what i am doing by your help. Could you look at that question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68339736/how-can-i-make-rows-show-or-hide-based-on-a-value-of-a-selectbox?noredirect=1#comment120779771_68339736 i think html doesnt sound anything on that page, but someone in the question wanted it, thats why i added.